# How to remove the characters �� from the JSON response using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Below is the JSON Response from the Server, How to remove the characters �� from the below Response using Jmeter

**Response :**
{"_id":"5d56cc5c31acfd001298e863","test_id":"5d56cc593801370012bdb2bb","display_order":"1","question_type":"MULTIPLE CHOICE","isbn":"9780393630749","status":"added","question":{"_id":"5d56cc5c31acfd001298e864","questionId":"5d4262bb56c1d800122fcb48","QuestionTitle":{"key":"","value":"","valueRTF":"","valueHtml":"��������\n

I have written the groovy Script. but it is not removing  the char.

*def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def var1= response.replaceAll("\�", "");*

and I need to use this Var1 in another request.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're seeing these question marks due to [encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding) problems, try setting [`file.encoding` property](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html) to `UTF-8` in *system.properties* file and restart JMeter, most probably you will see normal text instead of the question marks.

If for some reason the above hint is not applicable I would recommend replacing the whole `valueHtml` attribute value using [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html), the relevant code would be something like:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()))
builder.content.question.QuestionTitle.valueHtml = ''
vars.put('Var1', builder.toPrettyString())
```

As the result you will have the same JSON structure with empty `valueHtml` attribute.

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri  The valueHtml contains   text along with this character.  I need to remove that character only not the Text .... valueHtml":"<font face=\"Times New Roman\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt\"><font color=\"#000000\">��������\n </font></span></font> <font color=\"#000000\"></font> <font face=\"Times New Roman\"><font color=\"#000000\">According to Coulomb’s law, which ionic compound A–D has the smallest electrostatic potential energy

Answer (score 0):

As it is a JSON Response, add `JSON Extractor` Post Processor to the Parent Sampler from where the Response is expected. Extract whole JSON with following settings:

[image]

Now, use a `JSR223 Sampler`, with following code in script area:

```
String var1 = vars.get("jsonOutput");
log.info("Output: " + var1);
String replaceString=var1.replace('?','-'); // replace with whatever you want to, I am replacing it with '-'
log.info("Output: " + replaceString);
vars.put("NewString", replaceString);
```

Afterwards, you can use `${NewString}` wherever you want.